# How do I find and replace string of # (pound) characters in vim?

Tags: vim, sed

I have a file where I have comments like `######### Utility Functions #######`. I am trying to clean it up and make it something like `# Utility Functions #` which requires me to match a string of more than one pound signs and replace it with a single pound sign.

I have tried the following

```
:%s/#+/#/gc
:%s/"#"+/#/gc
:%s/\#+/#/gc
:%s/(#)+/#/gc
```

and a bunch more. As I understand # has a special significance to match multiple characters like * but in reverse direction. This would mean that I would have to escape it somehow to achieve the above. Any help appreciated.

Comment: `%s/\v\#+/#/gc`

Comment: Neat \v very magic was the trick!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try that: `:%s/\v#{2,}/#/g`

```
#{2,} " 2, means at least two
```

There is a shortcut for "more than one" in most regex flavours: `+` so

```
:%s/\v#+/#/g
```

works too, if you use "very magic" (`\v`), see `:h magic`.

Answer (score 2):

No, `#` has no special meaning, and `+` as you use it is just a regular `+`. You need to escape the `+` to make it a "multi":

```
:%s/#\+/#/g
```

See `:help multi`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using quotes.

```
sed 's/"#"//g'
```

Comment: That searches for the literal string `"#"`.